# Azure Service Bus timeout exception with NancyFX

Tags: c#, nancy, azureservicebus, timeoutexception, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a `NancyFX` API, and when one of the endpoints is hit, I need to kick of a longer running asynchonous task that's decoupled from the endpoint itself. So I'm trying to use a `Azure Service Bus` queue.

I'm successfully writing a message to the queue when the `NancyFX` endpoint is hit. I can also successfully subscribe and read from the queue from something other than `NancyFX` (I tested from Linqpad).

However, if I try to subscribe from the `NancyFX` app, I get a timeout exception within a second or two from starting the app. I'm doing this in another thread which is kicked off from the `NancyFX` `Bootstrapper.ApplicationStartup` override.

I'm unsure why this would be different than doing it not in the `NancyFX` app. I can't see anything of relevance in the `web.config` file.

Below is the code I'm using to subscribe to the queue ...

```
var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("Main", AccessKey);
var factory = await MessagingFactory.CreateAsync("sb://myapp.servicebus.windows.net", tokenProvider);
var receiver = await factory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync("MyQueue");

receiver.OnMessage(bm =>
{
    // Do something here
}, new OnMessageOptions
{
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
});
```

Below is the exception ...

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: A timeout has occurred during the operation. b6b8e25a-714f-4f55-8a79-91e390f47a96_G25 (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.TimeoutException: A timeout has occurred during the operation.
>   ).

And here is the callstack when I caught it in the debugger ...

> Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message wcfMessage) Line 463  C#
>       Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(System.IAsyncResult result) Line 313 C#
>       Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.OnMessageReceived(System.IAsyncResult result) Line 381 C#
>       System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously)  Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(System.IAsyncResult result)  Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result)  Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously)  Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(object state)   Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(object state)  Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result)  Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(object result, System.IntPtr userToken)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(int readBytes, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ReadFrameCallback(System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(int result)  Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(int bytes)  Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult transportResult) Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously)  Unknown
>       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(object state) Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError socketError, int bytesTransferred, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags flags)   Unknown
>       System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: Once you get it resolved with MSFT support, would be nice to update the question with a solution they'll provide at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3be99968-72ce-4e3b-ae33-88aa65734401/azure-service-bus-timeout-exception-with-nancyfx?forum=servbus

Comment: @SeanFeldman Yes, of course :) And thanks for your answer below - I hadn't realised that was a tracking id :)

Answer (score 1):

The exception you got is an indication of the client not being able to go past ASB gateway to talk to the backend. You could use the provided tracking ID (`b6b8e25a-714f-4f55-8a79-91e390f47a96_G25`) to open a support case. In case that exception persists, try a different namespace to see if that rules it out.